# firebase.storage().ref().getDownloadURL() won't run

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage and save the downloadURL in Firestore, but when my code is running, .getDownloadURL() won't run. The image uploads, but after that, nothing happens. My code is below. I've tried with several images.

```
const task = firebase.storage().ref('/hendingar/' + img.name).put(img)

task.then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Img ')
  snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL((url) => {
    console.log('Url')
    firebase.firestore().collection('hendingar').add({
      title: title,
      description: description,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      place: infoPlace,
      prices: temp_arr,
      img: url,
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Success')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you try adding `.catch((error) => console.log(error))` to `getDownloadURL()` and share a screenshot of output if any?

Comment: Are you saying that 'Img' never prints out? or 'Url' never prints out? You should also try to return `getDownloadUrl`, and use another .then in a promise chain

Comment: No output from .catch(). 'Img' prints out, but not 'Url'.

Comment: @Dharmaraj "I get Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)." But there is no server response, im just running the node JS file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting any results or logs after `console.log('Img ')` because you're not chaining the promise properly. You must call the `getDownloadURL()` before chaining `.then()`. See code below:

```
const task = firebase.storage().ref('/hendingar/' + img.name).put(img)

// Uploads the file to Firebase Storage.
task.then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Img')
  // You can also put the creation of Firestore Document here.
  // (If you want it to create the document before getting the download URL.)
  
 // Calls the `getDownloadURL()` method.
 snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
  .then((url) => {
    // Returns the Download URL from Firebase Storage.
    console.log('Url')
    console.log(url)
    
    // You can put this either here or before getting download URL.
    firebase.firestore().collection('hendingar').add({
      title: title,
      description: description,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      place: infoPlace,
      prices: temp_arr,
      img: url,
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Success')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  })
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Logs error if there's an error uploading of file.
  console.log(error)
})
```

I leave some comments on the code above for better understanding.
For more information, you may checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).

Comment: Thanks! It seems like my brain didn't want to cooperate yesterday evening :P, anyways, thanks for your help. Appreciate it!